# Using kundera as database driver for spring gives error

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, intellij-idea, kundera

I'm trying to use Kundera for accessing the database for my app (mongodb). However I'm getting an error: `Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE` when starting it.

What am I required to set in order to be able to use the database?

Full error message:

```
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Full log>

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:17260', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.0.RELEASE)

 2017-03-28 21:53:10.162  INFO 204 --- [           main] main.App                                 
: Starting App on DESKTOP-J12LM4I with PID 204 
(D:\--omitted--\resttest\build\classes\main started by Johan Vikström in D:\--omitted--\resttest)
2017-03-28 21:53:10.165  INFO 204 --- [           main] main.App                                 
: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-03-28 21:53:10.318  INFO 204 --- [           main] 
ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6cd28fa7: startup date [Tue Mar 28 21:53:10 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-28 21:53:11.648  INFO 204 --- [           main] 
f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' 
annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-03-28 21:53:11.718  INFO 204 --- [           main] 
trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-28 21:53:11.786  INFO 204 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'validator' of type 
[org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-28 21:53:11.833  INFO 204 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e1fc46a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-28 21:53:12.210  INFO 204 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 
(http)
2017-03-28 21:53:12.226  INFO 204 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-03-28 21:53:12.227  INFO 204 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache 
Tomcat/8.5.11
2017-03-28 21:53:12.369  INFO 204 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].
[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-03-28 21:53:12.369  INFO 204 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: 
initialization completed in 2054 ms
2017-03-28 21:53:12.669  INFO 204 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-03-28 21:53:12.681  INFO 204 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-28 21:53:12.682  INFO 204 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-28 21:53:12.682  INFO 204 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-28 21:53:12.683  INFO 204 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-28 21:53:12.773  WARN 204 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
[org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2017-03-28 21:53:12.780  INFO 204 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-03-28 21:53:12.785 ERROR 204 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I have no idea what to do with this. I've had various errors related to using Kundera and Spring these past 4 days and I've had to retry a great many times in order to debug. But I have no idea where to even begin with this. Also I am using Intellij.

If anyone wants any additional information feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Spring configs:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
https://raw.github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/Kundera-2.0.4/kundera-core/src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

<!--
    The mongodb installation must allow outside connections.
-->

<persistence-unit name="mongo_pu">
    <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>
    <class>main.storage.entites.UserEntity</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="kundera.nodes" value="192.168.10.190" />
        <property name="kundera.port" value="27017" />
        <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="test" />
        <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class"
                  value="com.impetus.client.mongodb.MongoDBClientFactory" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="main" />

<beans:bean id="dao" class="main.storage.DaoImpl">
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="userDao" class="main.storage.UserDaoImpl"/>

<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="mongo_pu"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</beans:bean>
```

App.java

```
package main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this: https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Using-Kundera-with-Spring and also update your question with spring configuration files

Comment: Yes, I've read that wiki-page multiple times. I'll add the spring config. files.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect, this might be due to spring-jpa dependency bring within bundle. Try removing it and see if it works!